Merge on one column if condition met else merge on another column
So consider these dfs:
data1 = [{'name': 'Muhammad', 'age_x': 20, 'city_x': 'Karachi', 'number' : 1001},
        {'name': 'Ali', 'age_x': 19, 'city_x': 'Lahore', 'number' : 1002},
        {'name': 'Ahmed', 'age_x': 25, 'city_x': 'Islamabad', 'number' : None}]

data2 = [{'name': 'Muhammad', 'age_x': 20, 'city_x': 'Karachi', 'number' : 1001},
        {'name': 'Ali', 'age_x': 19, 'city_x': 'Lahore', 'number' : 1002},
        {'name': 'Ahmed', 'age_x': 25, 'city_x': 'Islamabad', 'number' : None}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

Is there a good solution to merge these dfs (or indicate the matches in df1) based on number column if not None, if number column is None, then based on name?

can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Since you have different types in number/name, an easy option would be to create a custom key with fillna and use it to merge:
out = pd.merge(df1, df2,
               left_on=df1['number'].fillna(df1['name']).rename('key'),
               right_on=df2['number'].fillna(df2['name']).rename('key'))

Output:
    key_0    name_x  age_x_x   city_x_x  number_x    name_y  age_x_y   city_x_y  number_y
0  1001.0  Muhammad       20    Karachi    1001.0  Muhammad       20    Karachi    1001.0
1  1002.0       Ali       19     Lahore    1002.0       Ali       19     Lahore    1002.0
2   Ahmed     Ahmed       25  Islamabad       NaN     Ahmed       25  Islamabad       NaN


You can use the merge function in combination with some conditional logic to create a helper column for merging.

Create a helper column in both dataframes that contains the value from the number column if it is not None, otherwise use the value from the name column.
Use this helper column to merge the dataframes.

you can understand more clearly by this example :
import pandas as pd

data1 = [{'name': 'Muhammad', 'age_x': 20, 'city_x': 'Karachi', 'number': 1001},
         {'name': 'Ali', 'age_x': 19, 'city_x': 'Lahore', 'number': 1002},
         {'name': 'Ahmed', 'age_x': 25, 'city_x': 'Islamabad', 'number': None}]

data2 = [{'name': 'Muhammad', 'age_x': 20, 'city_x': 'Karachi', 'number': 1001},
         {'name': 'Ali', 'age_x': 19, 'city_x': 'Lahore', 'number': 1002},
         {'name': 'Ahmed', 'age_x': 25, 'city_x': 'Islamabad', 'number': None}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df1['merge_key'] = df1['number'].combine_first(df1['name'])
df2['merge_key'] = df2['number'].combine_first(df2['name'])

merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='merge_key', suffixes=('_left', '_right'))

merged_df.drop(columns=['merge_key'], inplace=True)

print(merged_df)

